# Slick slideshow in ember.js template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Hey guys im trying to use the slick jquery plugin (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in a ember.js template but its not working.I tried to put the code in a 'component', but that didn't solve anything.

Html:

```
<script data-template-name="application" type="text/x-handlebars">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="nav-trigger navbar-toggle collapsed hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                   <span></span>
                </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">Writers Week</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/schedule">Schedule</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/stream">Stream</a></li>
        </div>
</nav>
<div class=".container-fluid">{{outlet}}</div>
</script> 

<script data-template-name="index" type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1 class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 swag">Writers Week</h1>    


    <div class="your-class col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div> 
        <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div> 
    </div>

    {{Slick}}

</script>
```

Js code:

```
App.SlickComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
tagName: 'div',

didInsertElement: function() {
$().slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000
 });
 }
});
```

This is only displaying the images. The plugin is not running and the images are not looping... Any help is appricated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- Component names must have two words, [as explained in the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/defining-a-component/).
- You'll want to use `this.$()` in your component, so that you're referencing the component's own DOM element.
- A `div` is the default tag for a component, so you don't need the `tagName` property
- It's usually best to not override the default method of a component (e.g. `didInsertElement`), but instead invoke a method once the `didInsertElement` event has been fired.

So, your component may end up looking something like this:

```
App.SlickSlideshowComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  setup: function() {
    this.$().slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 2000
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

Comment: Could you please example what component you have added in hbs file and what you wrote in component?